# Failed operation exception while trying to fetch object from database

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch two objects A,B from database where the two objects will have many levels
Under A, there will be so many objects

```
A -> C -> D -> E -> F ....
B -> G -> H ...
```

i am able to fetch object B and its subobjects properly but when i am trying to fetch object A and its sub objects,its throwing the following exception

```
abc.sa.model.error:FailedOperationException:Get Object Failed:Database read failure:org.hibernate.exception..GenericJDBCException:Cannot open connection
```

While trying to fetch object B, if i attach debugger and go step by step,i am experiencing the same error
Hence i assume that it might be because  of some time out exception

Comment: Database read failure: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode , SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null,i am getting the above said errors  if i am trying to getch the object A without attaching debugger

Answer (score 0):

It's not happening because your particular object is not able to load, it's because you are not able to connect to your database and yes might it be a timeout problem. To overcome it check if all the points mentioned below are as expected:

1. Database should not be down.
2. The Application Server should reach Database.
3. Your username and password that you used for your database is correct.
4. There are enough JDBC connections available to connect to your database.